# Importing SQL File in mySQL no errors

Tags: mysql-5.6

I logged into the mysql from the command line using the following command and in addition to that I was trying to import the sql file into the database as follows in the same line:

```
[username@abc-xyz web_app]$ mysql -u root -pmypassword -Dtestdb < TestDB.sql
```

Where, `testdb` is the name of the database.

Note: `web_app` is the folder where I have my `TestDB.sql` file present which I want to import it into the database.

After running the above command, nothing happens but I see a warning :

`Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.`

Please let me know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751352/suppress-warning-messages-using-mysql-from-within-terminal-but-password-written

Comment: @ITSolutions Thanks but my question is not related with suppressing warnings.

Comment: I thought you were just trying to get it to work but it appears in later releases of MYSQL that this may just be the default behavior in the name of making functionality more secure. Are you looking for an answer to a specific question other than **"why is this happening"** or **"how can I get this to work as-is with a workaround to the new security enforcement of mysql from command line"**?

Comment: @ITSolutions The file is not getting imported with this command `[username@abc-xyz web_app]$ mysql -u root -pmypassword -Dtestdb < TestDB.sql`

Comment: Exactly, so you cannot embed the password into the command line and pass it as an argument with the `-p` switch in cleartext apparently with the version of mysql you are using. If you look at the answers on the post I provided rather than the question title only, etc. then you will see why and how to fix. I provided the post so you could look through it all (not just the question which I did not even pay attention too).

Comment: @ITSolutions I can get to the mysql prompt using the following command `mysql -u root -pmypassword` so I don't thing it's password related issue.